# How to get gzip compression as string

Tags: python, gzip

I need to compress a string into gzip, and get the output string like on this site: https://www.multiutil.com/text-to-gzip-compress/

[image: example image (from site above)]

but python's gzip module returns bytes as a compressed string.

Is it possible to convert these bytes into a string, or compress it in another way so that the output is a string?

I tried to decode in utf-8 but it gives an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The website you're using encodes the bytes in base 64. That will work, but it partially defeats the point of compressing the data, since it wastes 25% of the space. (64 symbols means each symbol encodes 6 bits, which means that 2 out of 8 bits are wasted.)

Comment: Yes, gzip produces bytes. That site encodes those bytes to base 64 to make them usable as “text”. Do the same in Python…

Comment: Some texts (incorrectly or differently) encoded may not encode to UTF-8. You need to decide what is best course of action in your case. Use original encoding (if you know that) , ignore, re-code or replace character bytes that are not acceptable as UTF-8 sequence. Most commonly is that you get bytes result where you assume string or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that website is [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) the output for display. I get similar (but not exactly the same) results with this code:

```
import gzip
import base64

teststring = "Welcome to Multiutil. This is the tool where you can compress your text or decompress your compressed value using Gzip(gz), Defalte or Brotli compression algorithms. Also you can compare the size between your source and result in bytes."

gzipped = gzip.compress(teststring.encode('utf-8'))
encoded = base64.encode(gzipped)

print(encoded.decode('utf-8'))
```

result:

```
H4sIAFSA32IC/1WPwcrCQAyEX2WOCtJ3+EXw5E3wvLZjG4gb2WR/tU/vFlEQQiATvszkRO3tSoTh
UDWkhmiH4ySOVjEtG1PcJxbiaRV9ymjErdB9EQqCj4AVDPzVPxMH/CetRHXJI/az3FbjvN5gx0vS
4MJui4XKFxHLSDpakZiu3uFP3X7cU0uzhHOZiTPjTua3q7fWEykPaJfaS5CM8zPo3QvUlCS87AAA
AA==
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps that you have to follow are:

- import the `gzip` and `base64` libraries
- Convert the string object to bytes
- Convert it using the `gzip.compress` function
- The output of the compressed object is a bytes object, thus you have to encode it using the `base64.b64encode` function and then to decode it in order to convert it from bytes to string

Let's start coding:

```
import gzip
import base64

exampleString = """Welcome to Multiutil. This is the tool where you can compress your text or decompress your compressed value using Gzip(gz), Defalte or Brotli compression algorithms. Also you can compare the size between your source and result in bytes."""


compressed_value = gzip.compress(bytes(exampleString, 'utf-8'))



print(base64.b64encode(compressed_value).decode('utf-8'))
```

And we get:

```
H4sIAASBd2QC/1WPwcrCQAyEX2WOCtJ3+EXw5E3wvLZjG4gb2WR/tU/vFlEQQiATvszkRO3tSoThUDWkhmiH4ySOVjEtG1PcJxbiaRV9ymjErdB9EQqCj4AVDPzVPxMH/CetRHXJI/az3FbjvN5gx0vS4MJui4XKFxHLSDpakZiu3uFP3X7cU0uzhHOZiTPjTua3q7fWEykPaJfaS5CM8zPo3QvUlCS87AAAAA==
```

Now, if we get the compressed text and pass it to the tool using the decompress function, we get back the original text

[image]

Finally, let's decompress the base64 string using Python:

```
compressed_b64 = base64.b64encode(compressed_value)
base64.b64decode(compressed_b64)

print(gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(compressed_b64)).decode('utf-8'))
```

As we see, we get the same output:

```
'Welcome to Multiutil. This is the tool where you can compress your text or decompress your compressed value using Gzip(gz), Defalte or Brotli compression algorithms. Also you can compare the size between your source and result in bytes.'
```